# Does changing an element's inner text interferes with their children elements? (Issue with audio element)

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I've got this Track component that I want to be able to play a preview audio from.

```
const Track = props => {

  const handlePreview = e => {  
    if (!props.track.preview) {
        e.target.innerText = 'No preview available';
        return;
    }
    e.target.children[0].paused 
    ?   e.target.children[0].play()
    : e.target.children[0].pause();         
}

return (
  <div className='preview' onClick={handlePreview}>
    Preview
    <audio src={props.track.preview}>Audio not supported</audio>
  </div>
)
```

I want to be able to switch the inner text of the div between 'Preview' and 'Click to pause' depending on whether the preview is playing or not. For some reason, if I add the code to do that, the play and pause methods stop working. I tried using ref instead of "e.target.children[0]" but it doesn't work properly either (the first time I click, nothing happens, but after that, it plays and pauses with every click).
I can't tell what's wrong. Help?

Comment: Yes, assigning innerText replaces everything in the element with that text.

Comment: You should put the text in a span, then change the text of just that span.

Comment: I thought that only innerHTML that changed all the content inside. I see now why it couldn't work.
Thank you! I'll use the span workaround as suggested.

Comment: `innerHTML` and `innerText` both replace all the content. The difference is only whether it's parsed as HTML or literal text.